# Fewer questions on superuser seemed to get marked as answered?

Tags: discussion

I am an occasional user of Stack Overflow and just started spending more time on Super User. Completely based on anecdotal evidence but it seems fewer questions with valid answers here get marked as answered as opposed to Stack Overflow.

For example here is an older question with a good response: [Stop UAC/Secure Desktop from dimming the screen](https://superuser.com/questions/211875/stop-uac-secure-desktop-from-dimming-the-screen) that was not marked as answered.

Again I haven't analyzed all of the questions and answers between the sites. I guess my question is: Are there social forces that make it more likely questions get marked as answered from one site to the other.

Comment: Like @slhck points out: go look at Data.SE and see how many questions are getting accepted over time to back up your suspicions

Comment: Just to show the result: both SO and SU are at %80

Comment: @soandos thanks for the info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have actual numbers supporting this?

> Are there social forces that make it more likely questions get marked as answered from one site to the other?

Yes, no. Well… Stack Overflow has a long tradition of users who have nothing else to do than complain about low acceptance rates of others. While these kinds of comments are deleted on sight, they often slip under the radar and with their somewhat rude tone get the OP to accept answers on their questions.

This brings another problem though, namely accepting answers that didn't even help you. We certainly don't want that.

For what it's worth, I don't think this is a big deal though. I could live on a site where a concept of "accepted" doesn't even exist. And I don't have the impression that too many questions are still missing a definite "answer" as indicated by that checkmark.

---

Regarding the question you posted: The OP [clearly mentioned](https://superuser.com/questions/211875/stop-uac-secure-desktop-from-dimming-the-screen#comment215093_211887) that this didn't solve their problem:

> sorry, this is not the right answer. Lowering UAC level to "not dim" mode will keep UAC, but will deactivate "Secure Desktop".

Comment: Also, many new users come to Super User thinking that it works like a forum or mailing list. They ask a question, wait for answers, and if they get one that works, they move on.

Comment: I did point out twice in my question that I didn't have numbers.

Comment: Good points. Again just trying to understand some of the different dynamics at work.

Comment: I know you pointed it out, it's just hard to discuss about that with any hard facts :) The communities are really a bit different, but iglvzx has made another good argument that probably applies to any visitors. @bra